# PyMongo - count of distinct values contained in two fields

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I need to get the count of distinct values starting with string "hx" contained in fields "to" and "from". This is my current approach:

```
addresses_from = collection.find({"from": {'$regex':'^hx'}}).distinct("from")
addresses_to = collection.find({"to": {'$regex':'^hx'}}).distinct("to")

unique = set(addresses_from + addresses_to)
count = len(unique)
```

However, I'm already hitting a MongoDB limit:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: distinct too big, 16mb cap
```

and therefore need to re-do this to some better solution where ideally I'd be getting the "count" straight from MongoDB without further processing in Python.

Can anyone help to find the solution? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [distinct() collection level operation:](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=distinct#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct)

```
addresses_from = collection.distinct('from', {'from': {'$regex':'^hx'}})
```

Comment: That results in the same error: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: distinct too big, 16mb cap

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use an aggregation pipeline using a [$group aggregation stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
addresses_from = collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'from': {'$regex':'^hx'}}},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$from' }}
])

for distint_addresses in addresses_from:
    print(distint_addresses)
```